# c# gRPC compression - how to know if its working

Tags: c#, compression, grpc

I have my Server and Client for gRPC in C#.

My Server implements the following in `Startup.cs`

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.AddGrpc(options =>
            {
                options.EnableDetailedErrors = true;
                options.MaxReceiveMessageSize = 10 * 1024 * 1024; // 2 MB
                options.MaxSendMessageSize = 10 * 1024 * 1024; // 5 MB
                options.ResponseCompressionLevel = System.IO.Compression.CompressionLevel.Optimal;
                options.ResponseCompressionAlgorithm = "gzip";
            });

        }
```

When I hover the mouse over `ResponseCompressionAlgorithm` I get the following tooltip text:

[image]

It says that I have to add the header `"grpc-accept-encoding"` in the client with `gzip` as the value but on other forums they say that you just have to add on the client the header `"grpc-internal-encoding-request"`.

In my client I have the following:

```
 string s = GetRootCertificates();
            var channel_creds = new SslCredentials(s);

            Channel channel = new Channel("localhost:5001", channel_creds, new ChannelOption[] {
                new ChannelOption(ChannelOptions.MaxReceiveMessageLength, 10 * 1024 * 1024), //plenty of room
            });

            var invoker = channel.Intercept(new ClientLoggerInterceptor());

            var client = new Greeter.GreeterClient(invoker);

            var headers = new Metadata();
            headers.Add("grpc-internal-encoding-request", "gzip");
            //headers.Add("grpc-accept-encoding", "gzip");
            headers.Add("requester", "cliente");

            // deadline is the timeout in sedconds
            var callOptions = new CallOptions().WithHeaders(headers).WithDeadline(DateTime.UtcNow.AddSeconds(15)).WithWaitForReady(false);

         
            DataSetResponse response = await client.GetPatientInfoAsync(new PatientInfoRequest { Uid = "DF24387B-815D-4E06-AD76-9E9E3C255118", LoadContractsOnDemand = false }, callOptions);
```

If I instead of sending `"grpc-internal-encoding-request"` header I send `"grpc-accept-encoding"` I get the following exception:

[image]

> Anyway, with `"grpc-internal-encoding-request"` I don't get any exception but I need to make sure that the compression is really happening. How can I log the size before and after compression?

> And the second thing is just to make sure that I'm doing it right.

Comment: From that look of error message it seems client already sends "grpc-accept-encoding" by default

Comment: Yes that could be, do you think in a way to test that compression is really working so payload sent and received is compressed?